# How to create an directory inside the documents directory of my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, file

I would like to store files in a specific directory inside the documents directory, so that I can iterate over all these files and show them to the user for selection. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yups,You can do it like:

```
NSString *rootString = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    self.root = [rootString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DirectoryName"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:root isDirectory:YES] == NO)
    {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:root attributes:nil];
    }
```

And For retrieving you can do this:

```
NSError *error;

NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:root error:&error];
```

Hope this helps,

Thanks,
Madhup

Comment: Thanks Madhup. I'm getting an error like "warning: passing argument 2 of 'fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:' makes pointer from integer without a cast". What does that mean?

Comment: @mystify: can you tell me what are you doing?

Comment: Can you pls tell whats the variable type of `root` over here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

[Use `-[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:).

(The [standard POSIX `mkdir(2)`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/mkdir.html) also works.)